# What is the Right Way to Perform UI Related Operations in Unity using Socket IO

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, socket.io

I have been using socket io for few months now. I had a lot of problem with socket while implementing it in unity. But my main issue is when I receive message/data from socket connection I cannot just call a method to perform some UI related operations. What I came up with to have a boolean variable and do specific operation when the bool is true and perform something inside `Update()` which I feel is not the efficient way to do.

Example:

```
public GameObject IdleGo;
bool isDone = false;
Socket socket;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
   InitSocket();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(isDone)
    {
        isDone = false;
        IdleGo.SetActive(true);
    }
}

void InitSocket()
{
    if (socket == null)
    {
        socket = IO.Socket(ServerURL);
        socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
        {
            Debug.Log("connecting..");

            socket.On("response", (data) =>
            {
                Debug.Log("response: " + data);
                
                if (data == "connected")
                {
                    isDone = true;
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I would love to know how the whole process of socket is done with Unity since I am going to make a multiplayer game as well in near future.

Thanks.

Comment: you should perform cpu/io/network bound operations seperate from UI thread, here calling update in sync would result in poor UI responsiveness

Comment: That's one way to go but actually you should probably love the entire socket code into a thread/task so it doesn't cause any freezes

Comment: Well I don't know why its been downvoted since I cant seem to find an answer. There are already common question in stackoverflow and they are top questions and top voted..

Comment: @derHugo Thanks for the suggestion. Can you guide me to how can I do that safely in unity?

Answer (score 2):

I would move this entire socket thing to a background thread to avoid any blocking.

For awaiting the result in the Unity main thread `Update` and a `bool` flag is ok but I usually rather use something like

```
public GameObject IdleGo;

private Socket socket;

// A thread-safe queue for passing a callback into the next Update call
private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Action> _mainThreadhActions = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();

// Yes! You can make Start return IEnumerator
// In this case Unity automatically starts it as a Coroutine instead
private IEnumerator Start()
{
    // Create a new thread in order to run the InitSocketThread method
    var thread = new Thread(InitSocketThread);
    // start the thread
    thread.Start();

    // Wait until a callback action is added to the queue
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => _mainThreadhActions.Count > 0);

    // If this fails something is wrong ^^
    // simply get the first added callback
    if(!_mainThreadhActions.TryDequeue(out var action))
    {
        Debug.LogError("Whoops something went wrong!", this);
        yield break;
    }
    
    // Execute the code of the added callback
    action?.Invoke();
}

void InitSocketThread()
{
    if (socket == null)
    {
        socket = IO.Socket(ServerURL);
        socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
        {
            Debug.Log("connecting..");

            socket.On("response", (data) =>
            {
                // Simply wrap your main thread code by wrapping it in a lambda expression
                // which is enqueued to the thread-safe queue
                _mainThreadhActions.Enqueue(()=>
                {
                    // This will be executed after the next Update call

                    Debug.Log("response: " + data);
                
                    if (data == "connected")
                    {
                        IdleGo.SetActive(true);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @derHugo. I will try this and let you know.